# Android Message when I try to rotate Camera

Tags: android, android-camera

When I try and rotate the screen from landscape to portrait or vice versa on my phone when the camera preview is active,it displays the following message in the `Logcat`:

```
 Error while configuring rotation 0x80001005
 ERROR: failed check:(eError == OMX_ErrorNone) || (eError == OMX_ErrorNoMore) - returning  
 error: 0x80001005 - Error returned from OMX API in ducati
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own toast when you rotate your screen:

```
@Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

            // Checks the orientation of the screen
            if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

Comment: you mean for debugging purpose??

Comment: Actually what you want to do when rotate your screen?

Comment: I have a custom camera,when I want it to function both in landscape and portrait modes.I have both `layout` and `layout-land`,I found that when I rotate my camera,the change is not registered,the `Activity` is not destroyed and recreated as soon as the screen rotates

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess: is it possible that you set the rotation to something which is not a multiple of 90°?

try this:

```
    if (portrait) {
        params.set("orientation", "portrait");
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    } else {
        params.set("orientation", "landscape");
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(flipped ? 180 : 0);
    }
    camera.setParameters(params);
```